# Light is working but switch is not

Tags: electrical

Total noob here. Replaced a ceiling fan with an LED light. Connected the green to green, white to white and the black to black. The light is turning on but the switch is not working.

Not sure what to do. There is another black and another red wire.

Please help.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of both the light and the switch boxes?

Comment: `The light is turning on but the switch is not working.` ...... how is the light being turned on?  ...... which switch are you talking about?

Comment: What was the fan connected to before?

Comment: Added the picture. @jim - yes that's what it is. The light is on no matter what position the switch is in.

Comment: Before, there were 2 or more black wires on a wirenut *that the fan wasn't connected to at all*.   Before, was there also a white wire in that bundle?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the switch?

Comment: Can you post a photo that looks into the back of the switch box?

Comment: Is it the case that you did NOT change the wiring at the switch? Or did you change the wiring at the switch when the switch didn't work? If you didn't change the wiring at the switch, then assume that the switch is wired correctly and all you have to do is correctly wire the ceiling box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a very common type of circuit, called a switch loop.

One question: do the unused black and red wires at the light come out of the same cable? If so, the other end of the cable is most probably attached to the switch.

Strictly speaking, you should test this by checking for continuity between the unused black and the unused red, with the switch off and then with the switch on. However checking continuity is something that a total noob may not know how to do, or have the equipment for.

Now, I usually test continuity using line voltage and an ordinary drop light. You can do the equivalent of that here by simply wiring the switch loop into the light circuit and trying it.

- Turn off the circuit breaker controlling the light.
- At the light fixture, disconnect the black light fixture wire from
  the black wire bundle.
- At the light fixture, connect the unused black wire to the black wire
  bundle.
- At the light fixture, using a new wire nut, connect the black light
  fixture wire to the unused red wire.
- Turn on the circuit breaker.
- Turn the switch on and off.

If this doesn't work, that is, if the switch still doesn't control the light, or if the circuit breaker trips, then you have some unusual wiring, and you will have to spend some time analyzing it. If it does work, you're done, and you can put the cover plates back on.

Comment: Thanks Breveleri! That worked. Your help is much appreciated. 